# Are there restrictions with FirebaseMessagingService in Android 10+?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I noticed some crashes recently on Android 10 devices

> java.lang.RuntimeException : Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.acme.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.acme/com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService }: app is in background}

To receive FCM messages, I use a service that extends FirebaseMessagingService and I start the service from MainActvity using

```
Intent(this, MyFirebaseMessagingService::class.java).also { 
        intent -> startService(intent)
}
```

of course I have this in the manifest file

```
<service
        android:name="com.acme.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
</service>
```

With that all in place I am trying to determine how this crash happens **intermittently** on startup for Android 10 and/or how can I motivate it to manifest itself.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client Use these guidelines. Also, you have no need to start service from activity. Remove that code. Remove start service code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCM does't need to start, when you intergrate FCM into your app, register it in manifest, then you can receive FCM

Read the docs carefully:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client